# What kind of infinite tasks are considered possible?

Tags: set-theory

During the proof of uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$ by Cantor's diagonal arguement, we find a number which is not in the sequence by making the nth decimal place of the number different from the nth decimal place of the nth number in the sequence. But, my question is, we are making up the number as we go and we can't make sure that the number exists after a finite number of steps. So, why is that considered valid? And such types of tasks come up a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematics is not based on computation. And infinity is not necessarily "potential", it is "complete" or "actual".

We are not doing a two-player game where each player challenges the other (i.e., Player I gives a real number, and then Player II gives a digit, and the goal is that Player II managed to avoid being equal to any of the numbers given by Player I).

More generally, when objects are *given* and we give a concrete definition, then the objects resulting are concrete. They are not "made up as we go". In Cantor's diagonal argument we are given a list of real numbers. And we specify the digits of a new real number. There it is, that real number. It's just there.

You can argue that perhaps we want to consider a function $f\colon\Bbb{N\to N}$ which is both injective and different from a given sequence of functions, $f_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. In that case we want to maybe let $f(n)=\max\{f(i)\mid i<n\}+f_n(n)+1$. So it seems that the definition here depends on the previous values, so we somehow do "making it up as we go".

But this is a recursive construction, and the recursion theorem tells us that given a valid recursive definition, there is exactly one object that it constructs. In this case, the new function. So again, we are not manually building the function $f$, we are using abstract methods to show that it exists.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thankyou very much for your help.